# Competition: When will we hit 2000 questions?

Tags: discussion

You have 24 hours to enter, with a date and time for when you expect us to find question 2000 on the front page.

Only one rule:

- write a date and time in the next 24 hours ([will be measured as per UTC time](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=1440))
- you can't write the 2000th question yourself.

Comment: I think you should add more flexibility.. The answer should be within the chosen hour.. so for example 11:00 will be valid until 11:59..

Comment: Well whoever is closest would be the winner...so you get a lot of flexibility, provided nobody else picks a time too close to you :)

Comment: ok, thats even better

Comment: There are other ways to game the system (aside from asking the 2000th question yourself)... deleting old questions would be the most obvious (assuming closed questions count; else VtCing questions). :)

Comment: well sure, if someone really wanted to, they could make new accounts too.  But it's just a bit of fun, so most wouldn't go that far...I hope :)

Comment: right, locking it now, let's see how we go :)

Comment: What's the prize?

Comment: As I said above, just a bit of fun.

Comment: History!!!! we should make one for 10,000 questions now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened on [14th June 2012 around 1500-1600 UTC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4960701#4960701).

Answer (score 2):

I'm picking the 18th of June, at 11:11GMT.

Comment: It looks like you won Mark, even if you got it wrong by 4 days :)

Comment: yes, he won.. I now announce you moderator of Travel.SE

Comment: W00t! Wow those last 30 went REALLY fast!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to pick 19th of June 2012, 0200z

Answer (score 0):

I think it will 20th June, 12:00 AM GMT

Answer (score 0):

2012-06-25 00:00:00 UTC

(plus extra characters to meet the minimum)

Answer (score 0):

June 28 2012, 05:00 for question 2000.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be 19th of June 2012, 15:00